# Load file form GCP disk not bucket to googlle collab

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud, file-transfer

New to GCP.Using free 300$ credit

1.>created VM instance. (Automatically created disk)

2.>loaded the data from Kagle. (it was zip fie so unzipped it.)

3.>for particular file pre-processing t want to use GPU, which are not available in free tier of GCP so want to run on colab

4>for that need to load the data to colab from disk

5>there is method already mentioned in coab documentation for loading data for GCP bucket but I don't have a bucket and want to load it from disk instead.

Thank you

Comment: 1) By GCP disk, do you mean a disk attached to a virtual machine (Google Cloud VM)? Google Colab does not have that ability. You should put your data on Cloud Storage and then access that data from Colab. 2) You can use your $300 credit to create VMs with GPUs. If your goal is "free", then there is no method. Cloud Storage and data transfers will cost money as well.

Comment: Can you point to the doc for creating VM with GPU by using $300 credit?

Comment: I do not think there is a doc that mentions GPU and credit. Your credit applies to all Google Cloud Services. None of the services are excluded from the credit.

Comment: Have you ever tried or guided someone for GPU with a credit or just guessing that none of the services is excluded because when i tried to increase the quota i didn't find any service free. if you have an idea how to do it please guide.

Comment: In order to create an instance with GPU you must first upgrade your billing account, you will continue to use your $300 first and after you use them all you will start to be charged normally https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Uploading files from your local file system](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=BaCkyg5CV5jF) method from your instance, you will have to run the test from the instance and not your local workstation.

A [Bucket storage of 2000GB](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/#id=a1bf6e6c-f1a5-4c68-9195-8839dc354628) only cost $40 for 1 month of usage and there is also an ["always free"](https://cloud.google.com/free/) option of 5GB. Finally you can [upload your file from Drive](https://www.google.com/drive/) where you can use up to 15GB in free tier